# ES6 - importing from 'myLib/component'

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

[EDIT]
So I was using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) as a reference, but failed to recognize that when they actually publish their lib to npm, they appear to only be publishing their `src` dir, which is why `import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'` worked.

So for now, I just added an alias in my project:

```
alias: {
  'component-lib': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'component-lib', 'src')
   ...
}
```

[/EDIT]

I'm currently working on shared component library. I have symlinked (via `npm link`)`component-lib` from another project, and I have a question about the imports.

My other project is being compiled / bundled by Babel6 / Webpack@2.2.0. What I want to be able to do is say:

```
import MyComponent from 'component-lib/MyComponent'
```

That's currently throwing the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/Embed.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'component-lib/MyComponent' in '/dev/my-project/src'
```

If I instead say the following, it works:

```
import { MyComponent } from 'component-lib'
```

I'm following an identical folder structure to [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) (which does allow importing in my desired manner), which is to say my `component-lib` structure looks like this:

```
src/
  MyComponent
    MyComponent.js
    index.js
  index.js
package.json
```

src/index.js:

```
export MyComponent from './MyComponent'
```

src/MyComponent/index.js

```
export default from './MyComponent'
```

src/MyComponent/MyComponent.js

```
/* stateless functional react component */

export default (props) => (
  <div>My Awesome Component {props.isTheHawtness}</div>
)
```

package.json:

```
...
"main": "./src/index.js",
...
```

What am I missing / failing to understand?

Comment: *"That's currently throwing an error."* What's the error?

Comment: Sorry @FelixKling - updated question with error

Comment: I *think* this has something to do with webpack and symlinks. But I thought this was fixed in Webpack2

Comment: Oh I see. While `from 'component-lib'` will load the `main` file configured in the `package.json` file, `from 'component-lib/MyComponent'` will look for a file or folder in the root directory of the package, i.e. the same directory that `package.json` is in `from 'component-lib/src/MyComponent'` should work. This has nothing to do with webpack reall, it's how Node.js module loader works (and webpack follows that rules): https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together .

Comment: okay that makes sense. so `from 'component-lib/src/MyComponent'` works. Without having to add an alias in my new project, how do I import without having to include src? The Material-UI lib I referenced just lets me import `from 'material-ui/Component'`

Comment: Why don't you use `import { MyComponent } from 'component-lib'`? Ideally, callsites don't reach into a package. If you want `component-lib/MyComponent` to work, then you have to move or copy the file or folder into the package root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135120/discussion-between-scott-silvi-and-felix-kling).